# ROBLOX - Why is this fly script working only in the Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

I have this code for fly, as a backpack item:

```
Name = "Fly"
pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197163993751
a = 0
s = 0
ndist = 13
rs = 0.025
siz = Vector3.new(1, 1, 1)
form = 0
flow = {}
function CFC(P1,P2)
    local Place0 = CFrame.new(P1.CFrame.x,P1.CFrame.y,P1.CFrame.z) 
    local Place1 = P2.Position
    P1.Size = Vector3.new(P1.Size.x,P1.Size.y,(Place0.p - Place1).magnitude) 
    P1.CFrame = CFrame.new((Place0.p + Place1)/2,Place0.p)
end
function checktable(table, parentneeded)
    local i
    local t = {}
    for i = 1, #table do
        if table[i] ~= nil then
            if string.lower(type(table[i])) == "userdata" then
                if parentneeded == true then
                    if table[i].Parent ~= nil then
                        t[#t + 1] = table[i]
                    end
                else
                    t[#t + 1] = table[i]
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return t
end
if script.Parent.Name ~= Name then
    User = game:service("Players").Nineza
    HB = Instance.new("HopperBin")
    HB.Name = Name
    HB.Parent = User.StarterGear
    script.Parent = HB
    User.Character:BreakJoints()
end
speed = 50
script.Parent.Selected:connect(function(mar)
    s = 1
    torso = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Torso
    LeftShoulder = torso["Left Shoulder"]
    RightShoulder = torso["Right Shoulder"]
    LeftHip = torso["Left Hip"]
    RightHip = torso["Right Hip"]
    human = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Character.Humanoid
    bv = Instance.new("BodyVelocity")
    bv.maxForce = Vector3.new(0,math.huge,0)
    bv.velocity = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
    bv.Parent = torso
    bg = Instance.new("BodyGyro")
    bg.maxTorque = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
    bg.Parent = torso 
    connection = mar.Button1Down:connect(function()
        a = 1
        bv.maxForce = Vector3.new(math.huge,math.huge,math.huge)
        bg.maxTorque = Vector3.new(900000,900000,900000)
        bg.cframe = CFrame.new(torso.Position,mar.hit.p) * CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(math.rad(-90),0,0)
        bv.velocity = CFrame.new(torso.Position,mar.hit.p).lookVector * speed
        moveconnect = mar.Move:connect(function()
            bg.maxTorque = Vector3.new(900000,900000,900000)
            bg.cframe = CFrame.new(torso.Position,mar.hit.p) * CFrame.fromEulerAnglesXYZ(math.rad(-90),0,0)
            bv.velocity = CFrame.new(torso.Position,mar.hit.p).lookVector * speed
        end)
        upconnect = mar.Button1Up:connect(function()
            a = 0
            moveconnect:disconnect()
            upconnect:disconnect()
            bv.velocity = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
            bv.maxForce = Vector3.new(0,math.huge,0)
            torso.Velocity = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
            bg.cframe = CFrame.new(torso.Position,torso.Position + Vector3.new(torso.CFrame.lookVector.x,0,torso.CFrame.lookVector.z))
            wait(1)
        end)
    end)
    while s == 1 do
        wait(0.02)
        flow = checktable(flow, true)
        local i
        for i = 1,#flow do
            flow[i].Transparency = flow[i].Transparency + rs
            if flow[i].Transparency >= 1 then flow[i]:remove() end
        end
        if a == 1 then
            flow[#flow + 1] = Instance.new("Part")
            local p = flow[#flow]
            p.formFactor = form
            p.Size = siz
            p.Anchored = true
            p.CanCollide = false
            p.TopSurface = 0
            p.BottomSurface = 0
            if #flow - 1 > 0 then
                local pr = flow[#flow - 1]
                p.Position = torso.Position - torso.Velocity/ndist
                CFC(p, pr)
            else
                p.CFrame = CFrame.new(torso.Position - torso.Velocity/ndist, torso.CFrame.lookVector)
            end
            p.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Cyan")
            p.Transparency = 1
            p.Parent = torso
            local marm = Instance.new("BlockMesh")
            marm.Scale = Vector3.new(1.9, 0.9, 1.725)
            marm.Parent = p
            local amplitude
            local frequency
            amplitude = pi
            desiredAngle = amplitude
            RightShoulder.MaxVelocity = 0.4
            LeftShoulder.MaxVelocity = 0.4
            RightHip.MaxVelocity = pi/10
            LeftHip.MaxVelocity = pi/10
            RightShoulder.DesiredAngle = desiredAngle
            LeftShoulder.DesiredAngle = -desiredAngle
            RightHip.DesiredAngle = 0
            LeftHip.DesiredAngle = 0
        end
    end
end)
script.Parent.Deselected:connect(function()
    a = 0
    s = 0
    bv:remove()
    bg:remove()
    if connection ~= nil then
        connection:disconnect()
    end
    if moveconnect ~= nil then
        moveconnect:disconnect()
    end
    if upconnect ~= nil then
        upconnect:disconnect()
    end
    while s == 0 do
        wait()
        if #flow > 0 then
            flow = checktable(flow, true)
            local i
            for i = 1,#flow do
                flow[i].Transparency = flow[i].Transparency + rs
                if flow[i].Transparency >= 1 then flow[i]:remove() end
            end
        end
    end
end)
while true do
    wait()
    if s == 1 then
        return
    end
end
script:remove()
```

The script is in a HopperBin Object in the game's StarterPack Folder.

Now if you try it on your own, you'll see that it will work, BUT if you publish the game, play it via ROBLOX(not the studio) and try to use the item, you won't fly.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since I haven't played ROBLOX, so my answer might be inaccurate.

First, you need to understand the difference between [a Script and a Localscript](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/LocalScript). In a nutshell, a script runs server-side whereas a Localscript runs client-side. Your fly script is expected to run on a player's client, thus you have to use a Localscript.

Your regular script works in build-mode because scripts are run on your client, and thus are considered as Localscripts. When you publish your game and play it, your computer doesn't work as a server anymore, but as a client.

In addition to this, as you use a localscript, you may have to change the following line :

```
-- gets the client (local player) on which the script is running
User = Game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
```

Also, avoid relative paths such as `script.Parent.Parent.Parent....`. You want to get the client's torso, so just use your User variable as per : `User.Character.Torso`. Do the same for the character's Humanoid object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the time to load not existing try this at line1:

```
repeat wait() until game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: please explain some more

Comment: Just write: repeat wait() until game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character at line 1

Comment: nah now it doesn't do anthing.

Comment: So uh.. any other solutions?

Comment: It doesn't do anything since you're using a Script instead of a LocalScript. Thus LocalPlayer is undefined. Read my answer for further explanation.